# Counting and Grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group and count information from a database.

**I have this data:**

```
column_a | column_b
-------------------
A        | 1
A        | 2
A        | 2
B        | 3
B        | 3
A        | 3
B        | 3
```

I would like the data to create a column counting the number of rows matching the value of `column_a` into `a_total`. Then I would like to group `column_b` values together for kind of A. The data should then output it by the `a_total` descending, then by column_b descending.

**I want this output:**

```
column_a | column_b | a_total | b_total
---------------------------------------
A        | 3        | 4       | 1
A        | 2        | 4       | 2
A        | 1        | 4       | 1
B        | 3        | 3       | 3
```

**What I have got so far...**

So far I have `SELECT column_a, column_b, COUNT(*) AS b_total FROM this_table GROUP BY column_a, column_b ORDER BY column_b DESC, b_total DESC` which puts `column_b` into order with the correct `b_total` but I am unsure how to also get the totals of `column_a` into `a_total` within the same query.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Removed PHP tag, has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE t ( a VARCHAR(5), b INT );
INSERT t VALUE ('A', 1),('A', 2),('A', 2),('B', 3),('B', 3),('A', 3),('B', 3);
```

/* the query */

```
SELECT xx.a , xx.b , yy.a_total , zz.b_total
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM t) xx 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(a) AS a_total, a FROM t GROUP BY a) yy 
    ON xx.a = yy.a 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(a) AS b_total , a , b FROM t GROUP BY a, b) zz
    ON (zz.a = xx.a AND zz.b = xx.b)
```